Verb agreement after a singular noun followed by etc?
I was just looking at some programming comments that are full of Euroenglish/ESL English etc, most of which I know how to fix into native "standard" English, until I came to this line:


But here we use a fixed array, so that .rgba swizzling etc work.


This feels wrong to me but logically makes sense. "Swizzling" is a singular and the only explicitly mentioned subject of the clause so a singular verb "works" sounds better.
But the etc strongly implies that "swizzling" is not alone. If it were an explicit list like "So that swizzling and twiddling work" or "So that swizzling and twiddling etc. work" then the choice  of plural verb "work" is an easy one.
I suppose it's because "etc." only implies that there might be other subjects, but there also might not be any others.
I couldn't find this specific case of verb agreement anywhere. Does it appear in any style guides? How do other English native speakers feel about it?

I don't see why you feel like [noun] etc. is a special case. Would you feel the same about [noun] and such, or [noun] and things like that? To me, they're obviously plural if you've added at least one "similar thing" to at least one explicitly stated [noun]. It would be the same with [noun] and things like that (if indeed there are any others) - whether the "others" actually exist is irrelevant, they've been referenced, so they affect syntax.

There's another related abbreviation, an initialism. According to Investopedia, << An exchange-traded commodity (ETC) is a security that gives investors who do not have direct access to spot or derivatives commodities ... >>. But off-topic here; it involves a renaming appositive as the parenthetical, of course.

@FF More than one anomalous example of agreement exists in English.

@FumbleFingers. Nope those don't "feel wrong" like the etc. sentence does. In those cases the appeal to logic matches my native speaker intuition. English is more full of things don't match my sense of logic that things that don't match my native speaker intuition. ("The car has damage" and not "damages", a "ten year old boy" and not a "ten years old boy") just for couple of examples common in Euroenglish/ESL English.

I'm baffled. Surely by definition, a native Anglophone's "intuition" about things like "plurality" simply reflects what he's grown up hearing. Which is always It's got damage and He's a ten year old [boy], never damages or years. I don't see how you can be intuitively drawn to a form that you never encounter. Particularly for Brits, rather than Americans, since even mainstream BrE happily accepts singular or plural for things like the government, the police, the company,... Where AmE is often far more rigid as regards "correct" usage.

@FumbleFingers: Those were examples of what would be logical, not examples of native speaker intuition. Nevertheless I've learned over the years not to trust native speaker intuition, even my own. In fact in this case my native speaker intuition is now conflicted after sleeping on it. I think Stuart F's comment has correctly identified what makes it feel wrong to me.

oic. It's wasn't so much  Stuart F's comment  there that clarified things for me. It all fell into place when I read your comment saying that you might understand etc. as being equivalent to for example. I see what you're getting at now, since in your own example, ...so that .rgba swizzling for example works would be perfectly correct, And there's an argument for saying that since etc. isn't really "English" in the first place, native Anglophones won't necessarily all agree on exactly how to incorporate it into our own language.

@FumbleFingers: I looked at definitions in a few dictionaries and most define only one sense, and the ones that don't make some other distinction I already forgot. This colloquial usage is something lexicographers and style guide writers might not have noticed before, and possibly because introspecting our native language is not always as easy as we might expect?

"introspecting our native language"? Well, I suppose each of us is different in that respect. For example. I cringe if I read (or hear a reasonably well-spoken person say) "I would of baked a cake", because to me there's just no way to parse it syntactically. But I'm quite comfortable with "If I had have known you were coming..." regardless of what grammarians and linguists think of it, whereas non-contracted "If I would have known you were coming..." just sounds like something a German might say (we natives invariably contract "whatever-it-is" to just If I'd have...)

@FumbleFingers We're drifting off topic but I feel exactly the same way. In fact it's a perfect example because some years ago I posted about "If I would have known" and only in the course of that discussion did I become I aware that all my life I had been saying "If I had have known" despite also knowing that "If I had known" was correct!

The abbreviation etc. means “and so forth.” So when it is appended to a list of even only one noun phrase, the result is a conjunction and therefore requires the plural form of a verb.

GrammarReference actually has << Note that a verb, noun, etc., is usually left out the second time it is used. >>. I'd perhaps use << Note that a verb (, noun, ...), is usually left out the second time it is used. >> And the ellipsis equally means 'and so on' here. And parentheticals may be offset with commas. ... ... I'd probably usually switch to the plural verb form, though.

It may literally mean "and the rest" (not "and so forth") but is often used more loosely with a meaning closer to "or whatever" or "and anything I haven't thought of" or "which may or may not cover everything" or other even vaguer things. So you need to figure out what it means in the specific context, not assume everything still means what it meant 2000 years ago.

Yes, here it is basically a metonymy for *that stuff we may use with fixed arrays".

@StuartF: Yes I think you've identified what it is about it that sets of my native speaker intuition! Logically I know that "etc" is supposed to literally mean "and the rest" but as a native speaker I know it is also used for things like "for example" and "or whatever it's called" etc. When used in such ways it does not necessarily create a list. A contrived example: "I saw a truck, pickup, etc."

Interesting, @hippietrail. In your example, what does the etc mean. The only parse that occurs to me personally is something like “and other properties [of the truck],” but that would make it a summary of a list.

@PaulTanenbaum: I suppose it means "or the like" or "or whatever you call them". Assume it was written by somebody who neither knows or cares about such vehicles and doesn't know if either term is correct, if they are synonyms, if one is a subtype of the other etc.


I suppose it's because "etc." only implies that there might be other subjects, but there also might not be any others.

That's not correct. et cetera entails others. The phrase merely avoids naming them.
[Aside: speaking of entailment, et cetera was used in Shakespeare's day as a euphemism for "tail" etc, in the lewd sense of those words.]
You will find definitions of et cetera that say something to the effect that it is appended to a list to avoid mentioning all of the other relevant possibilities individually. But the literal meaning is simply "and others" and it can be appended to a singleton.
The phrase is often understood in context to mean "and others that are similar" but there is no requirement that multiple items precede et cetera in order to establish a broader basis for understanding what would be similar.
Compare:

There's a section on the form for demographics, where they ask for your name, etc.


So you'd also use << But here we use a fixed array, so that rgba swizzling ... work >>?

@EdwinAshworth If by the ellipsis (swizzling ... work)  you mean to include "etc" then yes. "so that [swizzling etc] work". That is, "so that swizzling and others (like swizzling) work".  But if etc is omitted it should be works.

The ellipsis I'm showing is another way of saying 'and so on', not in this case indicating a retrievable ellipted string. As in 1, 2, 3, ... .

@Edwin I think you'd need to use commas to make it clear it's a list: "so that .rgba swizzling, ..., work." But either way it looks clunky to me and I'd use "etc." instead.

Perhaps only with ellipses following two or more actual examples, wjandrea (though the ellipsis is more ambiguous than 'etc').  I did observe the protocol with the numerical example.

@EdwinAshworth et cetera  has meant "and others" when deployed in English texts for hundreds and hundreds of years now.  I disagree with the contention that an ellipsis has the same meaning in natural language contexts.  I would not use an ellipsis as a substitute for et cetera in an English sentence even if  ... has the meaning "and others" in an arithmetic series, which I don't think it quite does.

Does it entail "one or more" others or does it entail "zero or more" others?

@hippietrail Neither.   It is plural and so it cannot be zero or one. It is not "and possibly others".  This is natural language not a List<T> that can  be empty.

Looking for supporting evidence, so far I've just found the upvoted and accepted answer atellipses at the end of unfinished lists. // Ah, Hodder & Gibson SQA Exam Practice: 'At the end of a sentence
they can be used to suggest an
unfinished list  ...'.

@EdwinAshworth  An ellipsis has no verbal sense. It simply signifies a truncation.  Whereas et cetera and its abbreviations do have verbal sense.
